# Capture the old and new vaues of a form filed during edit and updating the form in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a HTML form with several fileds in it. Using PHP and mySQL i was able to store the form values in one or more tables and retrieve back in the same form for editing and update it in the database.Now i want to record the values of the form fields that are changed in the form edit for reference. I want to record the following in a seperate table.

```
  1. old value of modified field
  2. New value of modified field
  3. field name of the modified field
```

Please help me here.how to perform the following functioanlity using PHP and Mysql

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: So what's the problem? Just check on every update which values changed and then add it to your new table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it

Comment: 1 is the data that you have already in your database. 2 is the data that you got on your $_POST/$_GET var. 3 You need to compare 1 and 2.

Comment: What Raghunandan Krishnamurthy is saying is that you should first see how MySql trigger works, and then create a trigger that clicks `before` the `update` query into your table. In that trigger, you can check if the old value of a field matches the new value of a field, and if it doesn't, you can insert a new line into your separate table.

Comment: "for reference" - just create a backup table.

Comment: ok thanks for ur ideas i will go through the triggers and try to find out a solution